# quotient of consecutive primes, an inequality

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A friend of mine asked me, if the following statement is true or not:

$\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}>1+\frac{1}{n}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

---

Here is my solution:

Assume that the statement is true. It is equivalent to $p_{n+1}-p_n>\frac{p_n}{n}$. Using this and Zhang-polymath8 result (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang), we would have $246>\frac{p_n}{n}$ for infinitely many $n$. Contradiction, because $p_n>n\ln n$ for all $n$.

---

Is there a simpler (with the use of less powerful theorem) solution?

Comment: Should the statement of your friend hold for all consecutive primes if n is large enough?

Comment: yes, for all $n>n_0$ with some fixed $n_0$

Comment: or, similarly, it would imply that there are only finitely many pairs of twin primes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the question relates to the [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds)

Results of Goldston, Pintz and Yldirim (2005) :

$$\lim \inf_{n\to \infty} \frac{p_{n+1} - p_n}{\log n} = 0$$

is enough to show the result. In fact, even the weaker inequality $< 1$ would do.

However, note other older results that
$$\lim \sup _{n\to \infty}\frac{p_{n+1} - p_n}{\log n} = \infty$$